# '_T' was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, macros, include, g++, string-literals

What file should I include to have the _T() macro? it converts text literals I think. I thought it is windows.h, but I have it included already.

Surprisingly, I could not find the answer on Google.

Comment: Actually I believe it is sucked in from `<tchar.h>`, or you could use `TEXT()`, which should be pulled in from `<windows.h>`; one is in the CRT headers, the other in the Windows SDK headers.

Comment: Or use `_TEXT` instead, which is defined in windows.h.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found information you asked for in the MSDN under topic [Unicode Programming Summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dybsewaf(v=vs.80).aspx) .

The answer is `Tchar.h`.